# Difference quotient $D^h_i u$ of $u\in C^1(U) \cap H^1_p(U)$ converges to $D_i u$ in $L_p$.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces

Suppose that $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is open and $u\in C^1(U)\cap H^1_p(U),1\leq p < \infty.$ For $V\subset\subset U$ and $0<\lvert h\rvert <<1$, we define

$$D_i^h u(x) := \frac{u(x+he_i)-u(x)}{h},\quad i=1,...,n.$$

I now want to understand why
$$\lvert\lvert D_i^h u - D_i u\rvert\rvert_{L^p(V)} \to 0, h\to 0.$$
My Professor stated that since $D_i^h u$ is measurable and converges pointwise to $D_iu$, this is a direct consequence of the dominated converge theorem. However, it isn't clear to me why there exists a function $g\in L_p(V)$ which dominates $\lvert D_i^h u\rvert$.

Similar questions have been asked before, but noone provided such a dominating function.

Comment: I'd imagine rewriting $u(x+he_i)-u(x)$ in terms of $D_i u$ (as an integral), which would result in bounding $D_i^h u$ by the maximal function of $D_i u$. But this would only suffice for $p>1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why would this only work for $p>1$? We have

$$\lvert D_i^h u(x)\rvert \leq \int_0^h h^{-1} \lvert D_i u(x+te_i)\rvert \,dt$$

and for $\lvert h\rvert <<1$, $x+te_i$ is contained in a compact subset of $U$ for all $x\in V$. Since $D_i u$ is continuous, we have $\lvert D_i^h u(x)| \leq const$ on $V$ for all $\lvert h\rvert <<1$. Is there something wrong with this argument?

Comment: You can rewrite the integral as $$\int_0^1 |D_i u(x+the_i)|\, dt=g_h(x),$$ now we use a generalized form of the dominated convergence theorem that asserts that it's enough to use the $g_h$ in place of a single $g$, *if we know* that $\| g_h\|_{L^p}\to \| g\|_{L^p}$, where $g=|D_i u(x)|$ and the norms are taken in the set $V$.

Comment: Your argument also works, but I'd be a little weary of using it since in the end we want to prove that the above convergence is true for functions in $H^1_p$, not necessarily $C^1$. But again, for the purposes of the question, as stated and with no ulterior motives, it's perfectly valid.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, you are right. My goal is to show this for $H_p^1$. However, by approximating $u\in H_p^1$ with $v\in C_p^1\cap H_p^1$ and using the triangle inequality, we have already shown in class that it is enough to prove the statement for functions $u\in C^1 \cap H_p^1$, thus my question.